# cgroup files for uninstalled software

Tags: software-installation, cgroups, uninstall

I recently had some issues with running pycharm-community where it completely failed to load, so I decided to completely remove the software and try again with a fresh install. Unlike most software I currently use, pycharm-community was installed by downloading a tarball of the software and running an install.sh script, so I couldn't uninstall with apt.

I decided to try removing all the files associated with pycharm-community in the hopes of removing it completely. Here is the list for all the files in my system that had "pycharm" in the name:

```
/var/snap/pycharm-community
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/name=systemd/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/name=systemd/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/name=systemd/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf/snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community.bin
/var/lib/snapd/seccomp/bpf/snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community.src
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-community_56.snap
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-community_58.snap
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-community_51.snap
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.pycharm-community
/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/pycharm-community_pycharm-community.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/cookie/snap.pycharm-community
/var/cache/apparmor/snap-update-ns.pycharm-community
/var/cache/apparmor/snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community
/snap/pycharm-community
/snap/pycharm-community/51/bin/pycharm.png
/snap/pycharm-community/51/bin/pycharm.sh
/snap/pycharm-community/51/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
/snap/pycharm-community/51/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions
/snap/pycharm-community/51/command-pycharm-community.wrapper
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_commands
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_commands/pycharm_test.py
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_load_entry_point.py
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_run_utils.py
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_setup_runner.py
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm_generator_utils
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pydev/merge_pydev_pycharm.txt
/snap/pycharm-community/51/helpers/pydev/pycharm-readme.txt
/snap/pycharm-community/51/lib/pycharm-pydev.jar
/snap/pycharm-community/51/lib/pycharm.jar
/snap/pycharm-community/51/lib/src/pycharm-openapi-src.zip
/snap/pycharm-community/51/lib/src/pycharm-pydev-src.zip
/snap/pycharm-community/51/meta/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/snap/pycharm-community/51/snap/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/snap/pycharm-community/58/bin/pycharm.png
/snap/pycharm-community/58/bin/pycharm.sh
/snap/pycharm-community/58/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
/snap/pycharm-community/58/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions
/snap/pycharm-community/58/command-pycharm-community.wrapper
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_commands
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_commands/pycharm_test.py
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_load_entry_point.py
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_run_utils.py
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_setup_runner.py
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm_generator_utils
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pydev/merge_pydev_pycharm.txt
/snap/pycharm-community/58/helpers/pydev/pycharm-readme.txt
/snap/pycharm-community/58/lib/pycharm-pydev.jar
/snap/pycharm-community/58/lib/pycharm.jar
/snap/pycharm-community/58/lib/src/pycharm-openapi-src.zip
/snap/pycharm-community/58/lib/src/pycharm-pydev-src.zip
/snap/pycharm-community/58/meta/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/snap/pycharm-community/58/snap/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/snap/pycharm-community/56/bin/pycharm.png
/snap/pycharm-community/56/bin/pycharm.sh
/snap/pycharm-community/56/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
/snap/pycharm-community/56/bin/pycharm64.vmoptions
/snap/pycharm-community/56/command-pycharm-community.wrapper
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_commands
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_commands/pycharm_test.py
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_load_entry_point.py
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_run_utils.py
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_setup_runner.py
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm_generator_utils
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pydev/merge_pydev_pycharm.txt
/snap/pycharm-community/56/helpers/pydev/pycharm-readme.txt
/snap/pycharm-community/56/lib/pycharm-pydev.jar
/snap/pycharm-community/56/lib/pycharm.jar
/snap/pycharm-community/56/lib/src/pycharm-openapi-src.zip
/snap/pycharm-community/56/lib/src/pycharm-pydev-src.zip
/snap/pycharm-community/56/meta/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/snap/pycharm-community/56/snap/gui/pycharm-community.desktop
/snap/bin/pycharm-community
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/snap-update-ns.pycharm-
community.26
/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community.17
/etc/systemd/system/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/etc/systemd/system/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-58.mount
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/etc/systemd/system/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.moun
```

I had a look into what the snap directory was and discovered I could uninstall pycharm-community with `sudo snap remove pycharm-community`. Now when I run `find / -iname "*pycharm*"` the following files are still present:

```
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity- 51.mount
/var/lib/lxcfs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/devices/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-51.mount
/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/snap-pycharm\x2dcommunity-56.mount
/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/snap-update-ns.pycharm-community.26
/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/snap.pycharm-community.pycharm-community.17
```

I was wondering what these files are; if I need to remove them to start with a completely fresh install; and if so, how do I remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't really understand what the files are, but `sudo snap install pycharm-community` seems to be working. I had some issues with opening a project which was linked to my github:

> Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
>   Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
>           at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
>           at org.intellij.plugins.markdown.ui.preview.javafx.JavaFxHtmlPanel.lambda$null$4(JavaFxHtmlPanel.java:100)
>           at sun.awt.SunToolkit.unsafeNonblockingExecute(SunToolkit.java:644)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.unsafeNonblockingExecute(IdeEventQueue.java:1397)
>           at org.intellij.plugins.markdown.ui.preview.javafx.JavaFxHtmlPanel.runFX(JavaFxHtmlPanel.java:134)
>           at org.intellij.plugins.markdown.ui.preview.javafx.JavaFxHtmlPanel.lambda$new$5(JavaFxHtmlPanel.java:100)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
>           at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:779)
>           at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:720)
>           at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:395)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

But on the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185156/javafx-on-linux-is-showing-a-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-s#21203726 I ran `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-bin libxtst6 libxslt1.1` and everything seems to be running smoothly now.